# Are there any values of $x$ for which $\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1} \neq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there any values of $x$ for which $\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1} \neq 1$

I got -1. does anyone see anymore?

Comment: That is the only point and it's because it is the only point for which the function is not defined. For every other value, it is well-defined and equals $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. If $x\neq -1$,

$$\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{x+1}{x+1} =1$$

If $x =-1$, $\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1}$ becomes undefined.

However, we can say that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1}\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1}=1$$

See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D).